# Is it possible to apply QSS styling for an entire C++ namespace

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtstylesheets

### Situation

In a GUI project with C++ & QT, I'd like to apply the styling with a QSS file. In the project, I have several classes in different namespaces in the following manner:

```
|-- namespaceA
    |-- subnamespaceA
        |-- class1
        `-- class2
    |-- subnamespaceB
        |-- class3
        `-- class4
    `-- subnamespaceC
        |-- class5
        `-- class6
|-- namespaceB
    `-- class7
`-- namespaceC
    `-- class8
```

According to [The Style Sheet Syntax](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#widgets-inside-c-namespaces), styles can be applied for a class in a namespace like this:

```
namespace--class selector
{
    ...
}
```

Now lets say I wanted to set the text color for every QLabel in all classes underneath `namespaceA` (classes 1-6).

### Possible workarounds

Obviously this can be done for each of the classes individually:

```
namespaceA--subnamespaceA--class1 QLabel,
namespaceA--subnamespaceA--class2 QLabel,
namespaceA--subnamespaceB--class3 QLabel,
namespaceA--subnamespaceB--class4 QLabel,
namespaceA--subnamespaceC--class5 QLabel,
namespaceA--subnamespaceC--class6 QLabel
{
    color: red;
}
```

Another possibility would be a global definition in combination with a namespace-specific object name (`QLabel::setObjectName("objectInNamespaceA")`), matched with the ID selector:

```
QLabel#objectInNamespaceA
{
    color: red;
}
```

### Question

Since both solutions are somewhat inflexible and lead to more (unnecessary) code I'm wondering if this could be done somehow like the following, non-working approach?

```
namespaceA QLabel
{
    color: red;
}
```